# Looping an array to collect in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails 3.2. I have the following:

```
FRUITS = %w(
  apple
  orange
)

FRUITS.each do |fruit|
  define_method "#{fruit}" do
    stalls.collect(&:fruit).join(' ')
  end
end
```

The expected result is:

```
def apple
  stalls.collect(&:apple).join(' ')
end

def orange
  stalls.collect(&:orange).join(' ')
end
```

I've got a problem returning the `fruit` in `.collect(&:fruit)`. What should I change? Thanks.

Comment: -1 for not posting [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use full block form (not the `#to_proc` shortcut)

```
FRUITS.each do |fruit|
  define_method "#{fruit}" do
    stalls.collect{|st| st.send(fruit.to_sym)}.join(' ')
  end
end
```

Comment: what this code is doing,what I understood is,methods are being created dynamically inside the `each` method,then from inside the `collect` method, which method are being called ? :(

Comment: Dynamic data transformer, as far as I understand.

Comment: Sergio, I think you need to add .to_sym to the fruit.  You need to send `:apple` instead of the string `apple`.  `stalls.collect{|st| st.send(fruit.to_sym)}.join(' ')`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the symbol `:fruit` in your call to collect, so the generated methods will be like:

```
def orange
  stalls.collect(&:fruit).join(' ')
end
```

You need to create the symbol from the `fruit` string (using [`String#to_sym`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_sym)) like this:

```
FRUITS.each do |fruit|
  define_method "#{fruit}" do
    stalls.collect(&fruit.to_sym).join(' ')
  end
end
```